# how to read a multiline element from PySimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.7, pysimplegui

My program stub looks like this:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text("Geheime Nachricht eintippen:")],
          [sg.Multiline(size=(70,4),key="GEHEIM")],
          [sg.Spin([i for i in range(1,26)], initial_value=12, key="SS"), sg.Text("Schlüssel zwischen 1 und 25 wählen")],
          [sg.Radio("Codieren:", "RADIO1", key="XX" ,default=True),
           sg.Radio("Decodieren:","RADIO1", key="YY")],
          [sg.Text("ERGEBNIS:")],
          [sg.Multiline(size=(70,4),key="AUSGABE")],
          [sg.Button("Weiter"), sg.Button("Ende")]]

window = sg.Window("Geheimcode", layout)

while True:  # Ereignisschleife
    event, values  = window.Read()
    geheimertext = values("GEHEIM")
    print(values("GEHEIM"))
    schluessel = int(values["SS"])
    print ("Schlüssel = ", schluessel)
    if values["XX"] == True:
        codedecode = "C"
        print("wir codieren:",codedecode)
    else:
        codedecode = "D"
        print("wir decodieren:",codedecode)
    if event is None or event == "Ende":
        break
window.Close()
```

The program-line geheimertext = values("GEHEIM") gives this error:
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
I quess that the multiline generates a dictonary in the dictionary values?

so my simple newbie-question is how to read the multiline of a gui made with pysimpleGUI

Comment: The error is happening because you're taking a dictionary (values) and using () after it which looks like a call.  The values returned are a dictionary.  PRINT the dictionary itself and then determine what to do with the contents of it.   This will show you what is returned from a multiline element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print(values["GEHEIM"])
```

`values` is a dict, and not a callable, so you cannot use () brackets (callables are functions or objects that have a function property). You can access to values through [] brackets. `values["GEHEIM"]`.

Comment: For a Multiline element, the entry in the values dictionary is a `string`.  Using a `join` is not going to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

ok, one possible solution is to iterate over the elements of the multiline:

```
geheimertext=""
for zeichen in values["GEHEIM"]:
    geheimertext = geheimertext +zeichen    
print(geheimertext)
```

Is there a better solution? Please teach a newbie

Comment: It is caused by wrong statement `values("GEHEIM")` which is a function call. To get the content of the Multiline element, should use `values["GEHEIM"]` which is index from a dictionary by the element key. Iterate is not necessary here.